# Working with Tags/UILabels/UIViews

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, tags, uilabel

Currently,

I am implementing a feature in my app that dynamically allocate UIViews with 2 UILabels within the UIView's subview... I have done this before but seem to be stuck on this for some reason.

Here's my code:

```
UIView *view;
UILabel *label;
UILabel *powerOutput;

for (int i = 1; i < [[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] count]; i++)
{
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*100 + 5, 10, 90, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 5, view.frame.origin.y + 2, view.frame.size.width - 10, 20);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    powerOutput.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SN %@", [[[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sn"]];
    [powerOutput setTag:LABEL_TAG+i];
    NSLog(@"%@", label.text);
    [view addSubview:label];

    powerOutput = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    powerOutput.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 5, view.frame.origin.y + 50, view.frame.size.width - 10, 20);
    powerOutput.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    powerOutput.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    powerOutput.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    powerOutput.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    powerOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@W", [[[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Pout_W"]];
    [powerOutput setTag:IMAGE_TAG+i];
    NSLog(@"%@", powerOutput.text);
    [view addSubview:powerOutput];

    [self.view addSubview:view];


}

for (int i = 1; i < [[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] count]; i++) {

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:LABEL_TAG+i]; // get the label with tag
    //NSLog(@"%@", label);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SN %@", [[[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sn"]];
    //NSLog(@"%@", label.text);

    UILabel *powerOutputLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:IMAGE_TAG+i]; // get the label with tag
    powerOutputLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@W", [[[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Pout_W"]];
    //NSLog(@"%@", powerOutputLabel.text);
}
```

I have also tried :

```
UIView *view;
UILabel *label;
UILabel *powerOutput;

for (int i = 1; i < [[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] count]; i++)
{
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i-1)*100 + 5, 10, 90, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 5, view.frame.origin.y + 2, view.frame.size.width - 10, 20);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    powerOutput.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SN %@", [[[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sn"]];
    //[powerOutput setTag:LABEL_TAG+i];
    NSLog(@"%@", label.text);
    [view addSubview:label];

    powerOutput = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    powerOutput.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 5, view.frame.origin.y + 50, view.frame.size.width - 10, 20);
    powerOutput.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    powerOutput.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
    powerOutput.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    powerOutput.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    powerOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@W", [[[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Pout_W"]];
    //[powerOutput setTag:IMAGE_TAG+i];
    NSLog(@"%@", powerOutput.text);
    [view addSubview:powerOutput];

    [self.view addSubview:view];


}
```

Which shouldn't have any issues because when I create a new view, I create a new UILabel that I add to the NEW UIView...

Heres a pic:

[image: simulator Pic]

So I create three views, okay good... But where are my 3 UILabels.... Also heres a log statement of the texts:

```
2013-07-16 18:14:26.945 PowerOneApp[14307:c07] SN 875222
2013-07-16 18:14:26.945 PowerOneApp[14307:c07] 53.50W
2013-07-16 18:14:26.946 PowerOneApp[14307:c07] SN 875225
2013-07-16 18:14:26.946 PowerOneApp[14307:c07] 59.89W
2013-07-16 18:14:26.946 PowerOneApp[14307:c07] SN 957188
2013-07-16 18:14:26.947 PowerOneApp[14307:c07] 135.39W
```

Really not sure why this isnt working correctly... Anyone got any ideas? This seems like a very trivial thing at this point, like one line of code or something.... I have done this before using tags with multiple views like this and have different values with respect to different UIViews, and the UILabels values change with respect to a UISlider I implemented.

So I have some experience with this issue but I am stump at the moment. Maybe tomorrow I'll understand what I'm doing wrong but at the moment.... I'm really not sure... If anyone can give a pointer... please do so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting your labels frame incorrectly:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x + 5, view.frame.origin.y + 2, view.frame.size.width - 10, 20);
```

Frame is already relative to parent view, so when you add parent's origin `x` and `y`, your label gets out of visible bounds. This works ok for the first view, because its `x` and `y` are small.

You might want to write:

```
label.frame = CGRectMake(10, 12, view.frame.size.width - 10, 20);
```

The same for the second label.

Comment: Agree, or better yet with layout constraints added to the parent view.

Comment: hmm... okay... when I get to the office tomorrow i'll give it a shot.. thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

```
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

***powerOutput.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;***

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SN %@", [[[_detailsArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"sn"]];
```

when the statement of `**powerOutput.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;**`  is **first** running, your variable `**powerOutput**` is `**nil**`.